# Default Range Validation on ASP MVC Model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to get ASP MVC 5 to  treat all type like they have a range min and max value applied?

i.e So this without having to add the range property to every conceivable property?

```
[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Value beyond accepted range")]
public int? Thing{ get; set; }

[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Value beyond accepted range")]
public int? AnotherThing { get; set; }
```

And where the property has a range attribute specified use that instead (an override default behavior)?

Adding a Range validator for each property is incredibly repetitive and tedious and breaks DRY.

I figure it could potentially be done in an editor template for each property type?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work it out:

**Editor Template : Int.cshtml**

```
@model int?

@{
   
    var htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary();

    var range = ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetPropertyAttribute<RangeAttribute>();

    if (range == null)
    {
        htmlAttributes.Add("data-val-range_min", "0");
        htmlAttributes.Add("data-val-range_max", int.MaxValue);
        htmlAttributes.Add("data-val-range", "value exceeds allowed range");
    }

    htmlAttributes.Add("class", "form-control");
    htmlAttributes.Add("type", "number");

}

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, htmlAttributes)
```

**Model Meta Data Extension:**

```
public static T GetPropertyAttribute<T>(this ModelMetadata instance)
  where T : Attribute
{
    var result = instance.ContainerType
      .GetProperty(instance.PropertyName)
      .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false)
      .Select(a => a as T)
      .FirstOrDefault(a => a != null);

    return result;
}
```